# Blender scripting - Incorrect texture add

Tags: python, scripting, blender, texture-mapping, collada

I wrote a python script that automatically add a texture to the DAE model.

Usage: **blender --background --python Script.py**

**This script gives an incorrect display of the texture:**

```
import bpy
from math import pi
from mathutils import Quaternion

myscale = 0.1;
daepath = "input.dae"

bpy.ops.wm.read_factory_settings(use_empty=True)

# Import Dae
bpy.ops.wm.collada_import(filepath=daepath)

# Rotate
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=-pi/2, constraint_axis=(False, True, True))
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(myscale, myscale, myscale))

# Change to orthographic view and switch to topview
bpy.context.screen.areas[2].type = 'VIEW_3D'
rv3d = bpy.context.screen.areas[2].spaces[0].region_3d
rv3d.view_rotation = Quaternion((1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
rv3d.view_perspective = "ORTHO"
rv3d.view_distance += 1000.0

# Unwrap
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action = 'SELECT')
for oWindow in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
    oScreen = oWindow.screen
    for oArea in oScreen.areas:
        if oArea.type == 'VIEW_3D':  
            for oRegion in oArea.regions:
                if oRegion.type == 'WINDOW':
                    override = {'window': oWindow, 'screen': oScreen, 'area': oArea, 'region': oRegion, 'scene': bpy.context.scene, 'edit_object': bpy.context.edit_object, 'active_object': bpy.context.active_object, 'selected_objects': bpy.context.selected_objects}
                    bpy.ops.uv.project_from_view(override , camera_bounds=False, correct_aspect=True, scale_to_bounds=True)
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')

# Add Texture
imgpath = "input.jpg"
img = bpy.data.images.load(filepath=imgpath)
mat = bpy.data.materials['m0DefaultMaterial']
mat.diffuse_intensity = 1.0
mat.specular_intensity = 0.0
tex = bpy.data.textures.new("SomeName", 'IMAGE')
tex.image = img
slot = mat.texture_slots.add()
slot.texture = tex

# Save Dae
bpy.ops.wm.collada_export(filepath="output.dae")
```

If I divide the script into 2 parts (1 part before section # Unwrap) and run their in Blender

1. open app
2. choose scripting mode
3. open .py files in run

I get right result.

[image: failure_correct]

I was looking for all the similar problems, but I could not find the reason for this script behavior.

Tell me, please, where is the error?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please add the script or just the relevant part to the question. Links may expire and then the question won't help anyone in the future. Have a look at [MCVE].

Comment: I expect it is from running in background mode, as there is no window or viewport, changing the viewport perspective is not actually changing anything.

Comment: @sambler, is it possible to create window or viewport? similar topics in the forum did not give me an answer.

Comment: Not while in background mode - that is the point, no window is created.

Comment: @sambler, thanks for the answer.